# Radius of convergence of $\sum a_nz^{n^2}$ if $\sum a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence $2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Assume that $\sum a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence $2$. Find the radius of convergence of $\sum a_nz^{n^2}$.

I have tried by using some conventional rule but failed.

Comment: What if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n r^n = 0$ ?

Comment: Apply the root test.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (2017/8/6) "Amusing" silent downvote, surely for mathematical reasons... :-)

Nearly every question on the site asking for the radius of convergence of some entire series could make use of the following *characterization*:

> The radius of convergence of the series $\sum a_nz^n$ is the unique number $0\leqslant R\leqslant +\infty$ such that:
>
> i. For every $|z|<R$, $|a_nz^n|\to0$.
>
> ii. For every $|z|>R$, the sequence $|a_nz^n|$ is unbounded.

As a consequence:

> iii. If $|a_nz^n|\to0$ then $|z|\leqslant R$.
>
> iv. If the sequence $|a_nz^n|$ is unbounded then $R$ is finite and $|z|\geqslant R$.

Let us apply these to compute $R$ the radius of convergence of $\sum a_nz^{n^2}$, assuming the radius of convergence of $\sum a_nz^n$ is $2$.

First, the radius of convergence of $\sum a_nz^n$ is $2$ hence, by i., $|a_nz^n|\to0$ for every $|z|<2$. In particular, $|a_n|\to0$ (take $z=1$), hence, by iii., $R\geqslant1$.

Secondly, for every $|z|>1$, $|z|^{n^2-n}2^{-n}\to\infty$ hence $|a_nz^{n^2}|\geqslant|a_n|\,|2z|^n$ for every $n$ large enough. Since $|2z|>2$, by ii., $|a_nz^{n^2}|$ is unbounded. In particular $|a_nz^{n^2}|$ does not converge to $0$, hence the series $\sum a_nz^{n^2}$ diverges, that is, by iv., $R\leqslant1$.

Thus, $R=\_\_$.